# How Spring Mapstruct gets info of Lazy initialized entity field?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mapstruct

I have two entities with ManyToOne relationship and lazy fetch type:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
 private Long id;
 private String title;

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private Category category;
}

@Entity
public class Category {
 private Long id;
 private String title;
}
```

And I have DTO:

```
public class ItemDTO {
 private Long id;
 private String title;

 private Long categoryId;
}
```

When I get items from DB I map them to ItemDTO with mapstruct, where I have this rule:

```
@Mapping(source = "category.id", target = "categoryId")
ItemDTO itemToItemDTO(Item item);
```

And everything works perfect, but question is how and where mapstruct in its impl class get data about lazy fetched category ?

I have

```
show-sql: true
```

in properties and don't see any additional queries, when mapping happening. Can someone explain to me how it works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with Lazy initialize Hibernate fetch id of entity, so it can make request for it later. Thats why you can getId() without additional requests. But if I would like to get some other info, like title then request would be send.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you map the `category.id` field from the `Item` entity to the `categoryId` field of the `ItemDTO` using MapStruct.

MapStruct this way will generate a mapping method that will check if the `category` field is initialised. If this field is not initialized, MapStruct will initialize it before calling `category.getId()` method.

It is implemented using a technique called **bytecode enhancement**. MapStruct injects **bytecode enhancer** into the compilation process, which modifies the generated code to initialize **lazy-fetched** fields before they are accessed.

MapStruct gets data about lazy-fetched category by calling `category.getId()` method after initializing the category field.

Comment: MapStruct does not use technique called **bytecode enhancement**. MapStruct is an annotation processor that generates human readable Java code. The lazy fetching is done by JPA once MapStruct gets the category through `category.getId()`

Answer (score -1):

MapStruct generates java code which looks the same as if it has been written be a human.

e.g.

for the mapping method:

```java
@Mapping(source = "category.id", target = "categoryId")
ItemDTO itemToItemDTO(Item item);
```

MapStruct generates the following code:

```java
@Override
public ItemDTO itemToItemDTO(Item item) {
    if (item == null) {
        return null;
    }

    ItemDTO itemDTO = new ItemDTO();

    itemDTO.setId( item.getId() );
    itemDTO.setTitle( item.getTitle() );
    itemDTO.setCategoryId( itemCategoryId( item ) );

    return itemDTO;
}

private Long itemCategoryId(Item item) {
    if (item == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Category category = item.getCategory();

    if (category == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Long id = category.getId();

    if (id == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return id;
}
```

The reason why a DB call is done is due to the JPA provider that you are using. Once you MapStruct calls `category.getId()` the JPA provider is going to do a DB call to fetch the category. The `Category` returned by `item.getCategory()` is a proxy that would do the lazy loading once one of its getters is called.